# Wordpress | Custom post type loop with odd/even alternating

Tags: php, wordpress

Cannot manage to create a custom post type loop with post alternating by the odd/even logic. What's wrong with the code?

```
  <div class="row">

  <?php 

   $wpb_all_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'cesta', 'post_status'=>'publish', 'posts_per_page'=>-1)); ?>

    <?php if ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

      <?php while ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : $wpb_all_query->the_post(); if(($i % 2) == 0) :  ?>

  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>  
    <?php the_content(); ?>
  </div>




  <?php else : ?>

  <div class="col-sm-6">
  <?php the_content(); ?>
  <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
  </div>


    <?php endif; endwhile; endif; ?>

    </div>
```

Comment: Seems to have an answer here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/113185/how-to-get-a-different-html-for-odd-even-posts

Comment: No wp_reset_query() required ?